# Equivalent of full control, modify and write in linux

Tags: permissions, windows, chmod

What is the equivalent of assigning *Full control*, *Modify* and *Write* permission, in Windows, to a particular user and group, in Linux? `chgrp`, `chmod` and `chown` seems quite limited in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Give a user full access (read and write permissions) on a file:

```
chmod u+rw file
```

Give a group full access (read and write permissions) on a file:

```
chmod g+rw file
```

If the file is an executable, you also need to give the user/group execute permissions (`x`), so it's `rwx` then.

For directories, `x` has a different meaning; it means that the user is allowed to list the directory contents, so you usually want to give users either no permissions, or `rx` for read permissions, or `rwx` for write permissions.

> quite limited in this case

It is actually, that's true. Many of the finer-grained permissions that are possible on Windows are probably not possible on Linux. Linux does have ACLs that you can set/query with `setfacl` and `getfacl`, but it doesn't support inheritance, which is IMO rather unfortunate.